# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list' python

Tags: python, json, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I get this really weird error when I am writing my Python code. It is a TypeError that I get to do with unsupported operand types. The error I get is below :

```
names_in_both = jsonDataprevFile.keys() & jsonDatacurrFile.keys()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Are you trying to intersect those two lists? or concatenate them perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are trying to find common keys in the dicts. [Unfortunately, `dict.keys` returns a `list`, not a `set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), which does not support the intersection operator. Just cast the output as [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects).

```
names_in_both = set(jsonDataprevFile.keys()) & set(jsonDatacurrFile.keys())
```

**Update**: as per python 3, `dict.keys()` returns a `dict_keys` object, which does allow performing `d1.keys() & d2.keys()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this

```
names_in_both = jsonDataprevFile.keys() + jsonDatacurrFile.keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get common elements of two lists

```
list1 = jsonDataprevFile.keys()
list2 = jsonDatacurrFile.keys()
names_in_both = list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
```